# XML Schema Simple and Complex Element alternatively

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm implementing an XML Schema model, but I don't know how to do a specific restriction...

A have an xml element which sometimes appears as a simple element and other times it appears as a complex element, like this:

```
<A>
   <Element>hello</Element>
</A>
```

Or

```
<A>
   <Element name="dsa"/>
</A>
```

Is is possible to assert that some elements can appear both as simple and complex elements in XML Schema?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an element to have both simple content (a string for example) and attributes:

```
<xs:element name="Element">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but you cannot declare that the element must have either the simple content or the complex one (the attributes) but not both at the same time - e.g. this is valid:

```
<Element name="dsa">Hello</Element>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing like simple element or complex element. Your above element representation shows that if your `<Element>` tag has value then it will show value like

`<Element>Hello</Element>`

and if it does has any value then it display with self-close tag like

`<Element/>`

But I am curious about how `name="dsa"` attribute is added to `<Element>` element. Can you provide more clear details? If you're generating XML schema using PHP then there is a 2nd parameter in saveXML(,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG) whereas LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG says that always generate complete element whether it is empty or not like

`<Element>Hello</Element>` or `<Element></Element>`

Comment: I'm not generating XML... I was given an xml file for which I have to write the schema. That's all. I'm just not able to say that an element  either has attributes or text, not both. I always reach non-deterministic models.